# Linking static library in Ubuntu for Rust

Tags: linux, rust

I am new using rust, and I am trying to use that library: https://github.com/SergiusIW/gate/tree/master/example
The exemple says to do cargo run --release
I have the error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_mixer: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image: No such file or directory

The exemple says to install https://github.com/Rust-SDL2/rust-sdl2#sdl20-development-libraries
So I did

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

But still does not work. And then I saw the section : Static linking in Linux.
But I have no idea how to used bundled, or  use-pkgconfig
Can someone help me on that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install `sdl2-image` and `sld2-mixer` development packages.

```
apt install -y libsdl2-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-image-dev
```

For `debian 12` above command works. You may need to adjust according to your OS type and version.